# Migrating from hibernate to another ORM tool

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

suppose I have used javax.persistance annotations for my classes, and if I have used hibernate to persist objects of those classes, what sort of changes do i need to do to migrate to another ORM tool? For example how should the following code be changed to adopt to the new ORM tool?  I understand I need to change the import statements, but what about the rest of the code?

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Driver {

    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.setUserID(3);
        obj.setName("shsdassaadfna");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you did use `javax.persistence` annotations, the rest of your code is Hibernate-specific so an ORM change would require a major rewriting of the code.

To keep your code JPA vendor-agnostic, you should have used only JPA interfaces, [entity manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) instead of Hibernate session, etc. Even with this, only full test coverage of your code could give you a high level of assurance that everything will keep on working as expected.

Comment: so using JPA interfaces is the best practice?

Comment: Yes, especially if there is a possibility of ORM change along the way (which, I must say, I haven't seen on any project myself).

Comment: if that is the best practice and if that facilitates to ORM tool change, why would people write hibernate specific code like I have done? (I just followed a tutorial)

Comment: Hibernate (as any other ORM/JPA implementation) has developed some features which are not covered by JPA specification. In order to use them you need to use Hibernate specific code. Not that there is anything like that in the code you posted, it is basic stuff. Also, as I said, changing ORM on a live project isn't really common practice so a lot of people make their mind about ORM they will use when the project starts, and there is no reason for them not to use vendor specific goodies.